# Displaying an array in xcode

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa

I am trying to display the an array with different factors of a number ("prime"). But instead of giving me the int numbers I always get 0,1,2,3,4,5,... .

```
        factors.text = @"";

        int factorsNumber;

        NSMutableArray *array;
        array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];

        for (factorsNumber=1; factorsNumber<=prime; factorsNumber++) {
            if (prime%factorsNumber == 0) {
                [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", factorsNumber]];
            }

        }


        for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {

            [array replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@"4"];

            NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d, ", i, [[array objectAtIndex:i] intValue]];
            factors.text = [factors.text stringByAppendingString:temp];
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d, ", i, [[array objectAtIndex:i] intValue]];
```

with

```
NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d, ", [[array objectAtIndex:i] intValue]];
```

The problem was you were only printing the array index, not the value.

Comment: sorry for the dumb question simply didn't notice!!

Comment: No problem, sometimes it helps to have fresh eyes.